# How to achieve Functional binding with ng-model (With plnkr)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dob column and values comes in this is in yyyy-mm-dd format say 2013-01-01 and I need to show it in input box as 1 Jan. I can achieve this by writing a function and then return exact value from that function. **But function could not be called from input box using ng-model where as it can be called using ng-bind in spans.** I can understand that function calling in input box will break two way binding. But what other approach I can use for this.

**http://plnkr.co/edit/pZDpypsxM1OA2JwFhjjp?p=preview**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dob = "2013-01-01";
        $scope.getDateOfBirth = function(dob){
            var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
            var split = dob.split("-");
            return parseInt(split[2])+" "+months[parseInt(split[2])-1];
        }
    });
</script>

<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-bind="getDateOfBirth(dob)"></span>

<input type="text" ng-model="getDateOfBirth(dob)"/>
```

Comment: Check into [$formatters and $parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers).  If you want, I could write an answer using them

Answer (score 6):

You can use ng-init to assign the value returned by the function and assign it to a model:

```
<input ng-init="myDOB = getDateOfBirth(dob);" type="text" ng-model="myDOB">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LsgQBnmboyQDwAu4qU3B?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. But doing that way, it does not participate in two way binding, If  I do some change in dob, it will not be reflected in input box

Comment: In above plnkr, If we do changes in second input box, then it will reflected in span, but not in first input box

Comment: Thanks, using this with ng-change to pass the model value to a controller function

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init to set the value and ng-change to keep the value updated

http://plnkr.co/edit/q1hg0R?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For dates, phone numbers, etc., you can use ui-mask.  Hope this helps someone!